# Como tocar um som usando o Mediaplayer?

Tags: java, android

Como posso criar um botão com SoundEffect utilizando a classe MediaPlayer ou outra classe qualquer do android?

Tentei utilizando o seguinte codigo que achei alguns exemplos, porem não obtive sucesso.

```
public void playMusic(){
    if(player == null){
        try {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(TelaJogoSingle.this, R.raw.song1);
            player.start();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (SecurityException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    }else{
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer, ao clicar num botão, produzir um som?

Comment: sim, um som de 1 segundo de duração +-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
//Declare uma variável de instância para o player
private MediaPlayer mp = null;

//Escreva um método para tocar o som
public void playMusic(int songId) {

    //Se algum som ainda estiver a tocar pára-o
    releasePlayer();

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(TelaJogoSingle.this, songId);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //No final de tocar liberta o media player para poder ser novamente utilizado
            releasePlayer();
        }
    });

    //Toca o som
    mp.start();

}

//Método para libertar o media player
private void releasePlayer() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

No `onClick()` do botão chame o método `playMusic()` com o `R.raw.xxx` do som que quer tocar

```
playMusic(R.raw.song1);
```

No método `onDestroy()` garanta que o player é libertado/destruído:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releasePlayer();
}
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. =D