# Som toca somente em modo debug

Tags: android, reprodutor-de-video

Porque o som toca somente em modo debug?

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
mp.start();
mp.reset();
mp.release();
```

Answer (score 4):

O "tocar" de um som pelo MediaPlayer é iniciado pela chamada ao método `mp.start()`. No entanto o som é "tocado" de forma assíncrona, ou seja, após chamado, o método `mp.start()` retorna de imediato.

Assim sendo a instrução seguinte(`mp.reset()`) é de imediato executada, fazendo que o som seja terminado.

A razão porque consegue ouvir o som em modo de *debug*, suponho que em *step by step*, é porque a execução do programa é mais lenta, fazendo que passe mais tempo entre a execução de `mp.start()` e `mp.reset()`.

Para ver como deve usar o MediaPlayer veja [Como tocar um som usando o Mediaplayer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97263/como-tocar-um-som-usando-o-mediaplayer/97265#97265).

Comment: muito obrigado, o exemplo funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 2):

UltraSeven,

Você está cometendo alguns erros. Vou começar a explicação com uma imagem que retirei da [documentação da classe MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare o que o método reset e o método `release()` fazer, ou a que estado eles levam o `MediaPlayer`. Após executar o método `reset()` o `MediaPlayer` vai para o estado *idle* ou ocioso e, após executar o método `release()`, vai para o estado de *end* ou finalizado/encerrado.

O que está acontece é que após executar o audio com o método `start()`, logo em seguida você executa o método `reset()` deixando o `MediaPlayer` ocioso, e o método `release()`, encerrando o `MediaPlayer`. Ou seja, o audio começa a ser executado e logo é pausado por ficar ocioso e terminado.

**Acredito que a confusão que você esteja fazendo é porque acredita que o o método `reset()` e `release()` só serão executados quando o audio terminar de tocar em `start()`, ou seja, que o método `start()` fica preso até que o áudio termine. Mas não é assim que funciona, o `start()` é assincrono, ou seja, sua execução acontecerá em paralelo as demais linhas abaixo.**

Espero que tenha sido claro, qualquer coisa deixe um comentário.

Comment: Seu esclarecimento em conjunto com a dica do @ramaral foram perfeitas. Obrigado.

Comment: Bom dia, passei o código para outra classe e está dando erro de contexto no create. Já passei por este problema no passado mas esse negócio de contexto ainda não consegui entender. Obrigado.